# How do I turn a timestamp into a javascript date object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

Turn a unix timestamp into 2008-07-17T09:24:17Z

How to do that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Unix time stamp is in seconds since epoch right? You can convert it into milliseconds (by multiplying it by 1000) and passing it to the date constructor like this to convert it to a Date object.

```
new Date(unixtimestamp*1000)
```

Then you can use the [Date APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to get parts of the date.

Comment: To answer the exact original question ("unix timestamp into 2008-07-17T09:24:17Z"): Use [toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) to turn Unix timestamp into an ISO 8601 string: `new Date(unixtimestamp * 1000).toISOString()`

Answer (score 13):

unix timestamp has an accuration of *second*, so convert to *milisecond* and pass to Date constructor:

```
var d = new Date(timestamp * 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's a valid date string, you should be able to get a Date object out of it using `Date.parse()`.

Comment: Date.parse("1304225607000") does not work

Comment: Cool. Then I guess a UNIX timestamp isn't a valid date string then. :D I learn something new everyday.

Comment: It represents some valid date based on a given epoch... but miles aren't feet. (See other answers).